# Ajax Cart Pro - view cart ajax?

Tags: ajax, magento, cart

We are currently using the ajax cart pro extension: http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/ajax-cart-pro.html

We are wondering if any body has found a way to integrate a "popup view cart" functionality or an extension that does this which does not interfere with the ajax cart pro extension.

Basically all we want to do is make it so when people click "Cart" in the header, a popup drops down showing the products in the cart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

hi Latox we have provided new Advanced Ajax Cart Extension please refer our link you can enjoy with this magento

http://shop.syncwebagency.com

http://shop.syncwebagency.com/n19-ajax-cart-advanced.html